# Facebook Payment Reports -- credential issues

Tags: python, facebook, urllib2

I've run into some snags in downloading reports through Facebook API.

From documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/payments/developer_reports_api/

```
#Example company access_token request

#Sample developer request for a daily detail report:
wget "https://paymentreports.facebook.com/234599349987627/report?
                                      date=2012-05-15&
                                      type=detail&
                                      access_token=234599349987627|aBc_dEFaEUZbqpatkrp8pbtwXyZ"

#The request above would return a file named 234599349987627_detail_2012-05-15.csv.zip.
```

However, when in a python script I am writing, using urllib2 to fetch the file described:

```
url = "https://paymentreports.facebook.com/%s/report?date=%s&type=%s&access_token=%s" % (COMPANY_ID, DATE, reporttype, ACCESS_TOKEN)
reportszipped = ZipFile(StringIO(urllib2.urlopen(url).read()))
```

I get an HTTP Error:
`{"error":{"message":"Access denied.: Access denied due to invalid credentials."}}`

I know that my `company_id` and `access_token` are correct, having followed the instructions described in the documentation to generate it (without errors). wget the same URL returns the same HTTP Error.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you enabled an app for payments, since facebook states on the developer page that:

> Before you can proceed, you'll need to make sure that you've enabled
>   an app for payments, including setting up a company to receive
>   payments. Once you've done that, you'll find your company ID and
>   secret on your Company Settings page.

Check out this page [here](http://blog.pythonanywhere.com/35/).

Comment: Thanks for the link and suggestion. I don't manage the actual app (just working on payment stats); but double checking that it is enabled. The documentation on Facebook is a little vague-- could the problem here be that the request needs to be signed using oauth?

Comment: My mistake turned out to be that I was using an access_token generated for my application, rather than one for the company.